# Correct use of log4j and Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, log4j

I have a doubt about the use of log4j with Exceptions.
I would like to log messages to my logfile and I don't know how to deal with exceptions.
I have to use only the exception (because already print in my log file) or something some this:

```
try {
        Configurations.getInstance().getProperty("DynamoDBProfileCredentials");
        credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider( Configurations.getInstance().getProperty("DynamoDBProfileCredentials")).getCredentials();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(new AmazonClientException("Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                "location (C:\\Users\\your username\\credentials), and is in valid format.",e));
```

or this

```
try {
        Configurations.getInstance().getProperty("DynamoDBProfileCredentials");
        credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider( Configurations.getInstance().getProperty("DynamoDBProfileCredentials")).getCredentials();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                "location (C:\\Users\\your username\\credentials), and is in valid format.",e);
        throw new AmazonClientException(
                "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                        "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                        "location (C:\\Users\\your username\\credentials), and is in valid format.",
                        e);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the question? How to log or whether to rethrow an exception? If you want to have the exception handled by the caller, then throw the custom exception and maybe write a short log. I'd write the stacktrace to the log where I finally handle the exception. Otherwise you'll pollute your log.

Comment: I'd like to launch the exception and logging it, but I don't know if it is useful add a log or it is sufficient using the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions are just signals/events; that occur within the bounds of your application. Logging of those is a different topic.

I understand your need for logging a helpful message within your application. In your case, you could trigger a log event either on the consumer of your method or directly as you did it.

The easiest case could be:

```
try {
  Configurations.getInstance().getProperty("DynamoDBProfileCredentials");
  credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider( Configurations.getInstance().getProperty("DynamoDBProfileCredentials")).getCredentials(); 
} catch (Exception e) {
  AmazonClientException ace = AmazonClientException(
      "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
      "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
      "location (C:\\Users\\your username\\credentials), and is in valid format.", e);

  log.error(ace.getMessage(), ace);
  throw ace;
}
```

or

```
try {
  Configurations.getInstance().getProperty("DynamoDBProfileCredentials");
  credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider( Configurations.getInstance().getProperty("DynamoDBProfileCredentials")).getCredentials(); 
} catch (Exception e) {
  log.error("Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
      "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
      "location (C:\\Users\\your username\\credentials), and is in valid format.",e);
  throw new AmazonClientException(e);
}
```

The example above is just an implementation but not an answer to your original question. To answer the original question, you have to have a clear picture of your API and the responsibilities that grow out of the API design. Do you want to log within your API or do you want to give the caller just a signal, that an exception occurred? Or both (like it is in the example above?).

Before using Exceptions or any other way, to propagate unexpected states, have an answer to the question: How should this case be handled? What should happen after an exception? Logging is no exception; it's just logging. After finding an answer, you can look out for the appropriate way to communicate unexpected states.